# iPad suffix for Images not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm developing a universal app in xcode 5 and im trying to set the background image for both apps. The code I am using is in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"city5.jpg"];
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    backgroundImageView.image=backgroundImage;
    [self.view insertSubview:backgroundImageView atIndex:0];
```

The names of both images are `city5~iphone.jpg` and `city5~ipad.jpg`.

The images works as expected for the iphone. However the ipad image never loads, the view just stays blank. I'm deploying on an ipad 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in `UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"city5.jpg"];` specifically `imageNamed:@"city5.jpg"` when you use `imageNamed:` it will look for a `.png` image not a `.jpg` image so in essence you are looking for file `city5.jpg.png` which clearly is what you want, so change that line to `UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"city5"];` and change your image files to be `.png`.

If you want to leave it as `.jpg` try the below.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"city5" ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

If none of these work I would suspect that your issue is one of three things:

- The image you are trying to load doesn't exist in your bundle. So make sure the image is actually in your project and make sure the target is checked by clicking on the file and selecting the target it belongs to.
- Make sure you don't have the image name spelled incorrectly.
- Or you are using a retina display but do not have an @2x image. Try changing your simulator to retina and see if it shows up.

And as a last resort try doing `UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"city5~ipad"];`

You also try doing `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"city5"]];`

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and neither worked, I even imported a new .png image to no luck. Everything still worked on the iphone as expected. Thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"city5~ipad"];

This STILL didnt work for the ipad view. The image is in the project, it loaded when I ran it on the iphone.....

Comment: @MartinJeffers What happens if you just use `addSubview:` instead of `insertSubview:`?

Comment: @MartinJeffers Or what about trying `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"city5"]];`

Comment: Much of this answer is simply incorrect. The `imageNamed:` method does not only look for png images. If you specify `city5.jpg` then it looks for a file named `city5.jpg`. The only time it assumes png is if you specify no extension.

Comment: @rmaddy then there is something wrong with it. I tested this before answering and when I had an image with `.jpg` put `image.jpg` into `imageNamed:` it didn't work when I switch the extension to `image.png` and passed in `image` to `imageNamed:` it worked find. I have also tried this in the past and gotten the same results, I do understand it should work but it clearly doesn't.

Comment: But it does work. I just created a simple test project. I put one jpg file in the resource bundle and I have no trouble displaying it in an image view after loading the jpg with a call to `imageNamed:`.

Comment: Well it hasn't worked for me and clearly hasn't work for the OP so I don't know what you want me to say.

Comment: Using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];` worked for me after changing the image extension to .png, it seems `imageName@2x~ipad` or `imageName@2x~iphone` works only on .png images